# How do you turn a line mesh into a parabola with geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

With the new geometry nodes in Blender 3.0, there is no attribute separation node to manipulate the x and y positions of the mesh points separately. How do I make the Y-position of the vertex be the square of the X-position of that vertex? [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Position* is now a field. **X -> X, Y -> X*X, Z -> Z**.. *Set Position*

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! It worked. For those who still struggle, make sure the mesh-line is set to start and end points.